# Editing office documents results in opening the documents in READ-ONLY mode - Only in Citrix

Tags: sharepoint-online, edit

In our SharePoint online environment, Editing office (word, ppt, excel...) documents present in document libraries results in opening the documents in READ-ONLY mode. Also, the document is loading very slowly while this issue occurs. This issue is observed only in Citrix environment. Also, it occurring during peak utilization times for around 4 hours.

Also, noticed that number of Citrix user instances per server during that time is around 20. This has made us think if there is any limit on open office connections per host system that is causing this peculiar issue.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Thanks.